# Keyboard shortcut for Gnome-Terminal profile change?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, automation

I have two profiles in my Gnome Terminal, one uses specific image for background. Would like to switch between them when I enter/exit  `Vim`.

So far, I do this by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and navigating to the other profile. But would like to have this automated.

Possible scenarios:

```
vim newFile # profile changes to Vim-one
:q # it changes back to default

vim confFile # profile changes to Vim-one
Ctrl-z # vim is suspended, default profile enters
cmd_that_uses_changed_config_file
fg # vim is brought back from suspension, profile changes again...
```

Now I realize that automating this fully may be difficult, so keyboard shortcut to do this is perfectly fine. I searched Gnome Terminal shortcuts but Terminal menu has three of them only: title, reset, reset and clear.

Any ideas, hints or pointers? :-)

Comment: duplicate question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/325235/command-line-to-switch-between-profiles-in-gnome-terminal

Comment: @Jacob, this one seems earlier. Jan 24th vs July 27th same year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preface: I am new, and having similar problems. In the absence of an answer by someone with a functional knowledge of these things, this is how I am approaching solving this.

'man gnome-terminal' offers some interesting options for starting new windows, or tabs using a specific profile. An alias to start an instance of gnome-terminal in a new tab using profile "X" seems like a reasonable quasi-kluge, and allows for existing keyboard shortcuts to switch between, and close tabs.

It would look something close to this:

```
    alias gtvim='gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=X -t Vim -x vim >&1'
    gtvim filename
```

For alias permanency, it has to be added to bottom of ~/.bashrc

I need to work on other things now, but that was my first foray into it. It still seems to open the command in a new terminal window, but still easily accessible from keyboard shortcuts.

Just as a side note, I am attempting to have all terminals with ssh connections to remote terminals open with a different color profile to help prevent commands being issued to the wrong machine.

Comment: Good thinking @Jortony! I should have mentioned I rejected always opening vim in another tab+profile due to fact I disliked such flow. Nevertheless, I've made inquiries into setting background image for Vim and short from coding this and compiling it with that option - there's no way. So, your answer will most likely be the best there is. :-)

Comment: Excellent =) my first social reward in helping out.