# Different terminal profiles for different directories/applications

Tags: command-line

I would like to have my terminal profile change based on either the current directory or the currently running program. Is this possible? If so, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/325235/command-line-to-switch-between-profiles-in-gnome-terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. Profiles in `gnome-terminal` are not automatically selectable in any way. You will have to manually select the profile to use in each terminal window or tab you open.