# run virtualenv in new terminal tab automatically

Tags: command-line, bash, customization, virtualenv

I am using virtualenv, so to start I have to say

```
source some/long/path/bin/activate
```

Sometimes (very often, in fact) I want to create another tab in terminal, to edit another script, or to run django shell etc. And after another tab's creation I have to say `source some/long/path/bin/activate` again. In fact, it is quite boring.

Is there any way to force terminal run this magical words automatically? So if I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> in terminal, and in current tab virtualenv is ran, terminal should open the very same virtualenv in the fresh new tab.

Or may be something completely different to solve this problem.

Comment: Posting a comment as this is a workaround not an answer, but you might try a bash alias to save typing. `nano ~/.bash_aliases && source ~/.bash_aliases` to create & activate one, then paste `alias X='virtualenv $PWD/bin/activate'` (change 'X' to be whatever you prefer, like 've').

Answer (score 5):

#### Targeting specific terminal emulators

Automatically running a command on creation of a new terminal tab would be a feature of the specific terminal you are using, and not related to `python` or `virtualenv`.

To have a broader range or answers the question would probably have to be *How to autorun a shell command for terminal emulator xyz*. For example, for `gnome-terminal` you can use custom profiles as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3856/15312, but this is an unportable solution if you decide to switch to another terminal or platform.

On the other hand, nobody wants to get locked to a specific terminal app, therefore the next option would be a more portable approach.

#### Targeting shell init scripts

If you control the shell that is running in the tab, then you can do it in your shell init script.

For example, for `bash` you can add the following lines in your `~/.bashrc` script:

```bash
if [[ -f .venv/bin/activate ]] ; then
    source .venv/bin/activate
fi
```

> <sup>For `zsh` add the snippet to `~/.zshrc`.</sup>

Whenever you create a new shell or open a new tab this snippet will check if you have a `.venv` folder in the current path and activate that venv automatically. If you create your virtualenvs in a folder which is not named `.venv` then adjust the script accordingly.

You might also want to override `cd` so that whenever you `cd` into a venv it will be automatically activated:

Below is an example for `zsh`:

```bash
function cd() {
  builtin cd $1

  if [[ -f .venv/bin/activate ]] ; then
    source .venv/bin/activate
  fi
}
```

#### Reduce typing with `virtualenvwrapper`

Specifically regarding `virtualenv`: you might want to try [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can help reduce the amount of typing, and make managing environments easier by providing autocompletion for virtualenv folders.

#### Backgrounding processes

And finally, as a quick workaround, instead of creating new tabs with the same env, you can suspend a currently running process (such as `manage.py runserver`) with <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, optionally run `bg` to resume it in background if you want to keep it running, then edit and save a file, and bring the original process back to foreground with `fg`. See [this](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-the-job-control-commands-in-linux-bg-fg-and-ctrlz/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I solved that problem using wrapper; but about solution with terminal profiles: it is very interesting, but does gnome-terminal allow to change profile of current tab by some shortcut ?

Comment: @polytheme: apparently not out-of-the box, according to https://askubuntu.com/questions/325235/command-line-to-switch-between-profiles-in-gnome-terminal, but an answer in the thread suggests workarounds that rely on a utility which simulates key strokes.

Answer (score 1):

I am using conda for virtual environments, and I felt the same need as your question. So I wrote a simple shell script for myself. Then I came across this question, and re-wrote my script for virtualenv usage.

1. Save the following code as a script
2. Name it whatever you want. Let's say `tab`.
3. Give permission to execute it: `sudo chmod +x tab`.
4. `mv tab /usr/local/bin/` to make it a callable command from everywhere.
5. The script depends on three other tools, xclip, xdotool, and wmctrl. If you don't have them, `sudo apt install xclip xdotool, wmctrl`
6. Yay! I was too lazy to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run `source /.../bin/activate` but I now can do `tab`!

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# Copy the clipboard content to restore later
original_clipboard=$(xclip -o)

# Copy the path of your virtual environment to clipboard
echo $VIRTUAL_ENV | xclip


# The following four lines open a new tab and switch to it.
# Copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191093/10953328
WID=$(xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"| awk '{print $5}')
xdotool windowfocus $WID
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
wmctrl -i -a $WID

# Activate your virtualenv
xdotool type --delay 0.5 --clearmodifiers "source $(xclip -o)/bin/activate"
xdotool key Return;

# Restore the original clipboard content
echo $original_clipboard | xclip
```

Tested with Ubuntu 18.0.4, GNOME 3.28.2, and it works fine. xdotools 3.20160805.1, xclip 0.12, wmctrl 1.07, but I don't really think that will matter much, will it?

Some part of the script is copied from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191093/10953328), as mentioned in the script itself.

Comment: If anybody's looking for a script to open a new terminal window, or scripts for conda, or scripts for macOS, the github repo is https://github.com/thebarbershop/environmental