# How to activate a gnome terminal profile from the commandline?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have set up several color profiles (e.g. some from [here](https://github.com/Mayccoll/Gogh)) whose UUIDs I can now list with

```bsh
$ dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
:7e95bbb3-a584-469d-8ae1-75a08287f55a/
:b79f95fc-b8a9-40b8-beca-5a1c1aee078a/
:833171c4-5fa6-4038-af36-e667ab2d876b/
:611439c9-b5cb-4b3f-9166-50897a705e29/
:5e0814a6-5f24-4823-9f54-d4accb9d9d92/
:403d9eb7-16d5-46be-864f-42d9651dda49/
:7bad96ca-3efc-40d0-9a8d-9e0c5d67738e/
:b0ac22f9-3c3a-42b5-ab5d-542d8465f2a0/
list
:4f99e9d3-caa3-4e88-8bc5-a1b6efe0b1ff/
:efbf6322-e497-4918-88e1-b44167d306fc/
:cb2c2176-2a0e-4e8b-83a9-ff2d9c456cb9/
:5ec02300-aa59-4bda-b33c-0e992f8adefb/
:de0d4915-5db9-4d58-a24a-7b7054ccfae1/
:7c6e6069-0dfb-48a9-bc3b-b4b2f486061e/
:484cd255-71a8-4655-b0cf-98b3f2e58abb/
default
:3bfaf350-2cf3-4f87-8ef9-cdadfc5f46bf/
:9e62c391-a298-419a-a0a5-32ad8adf0015/
:cc854d98-9559-4eed-9014-8e622bb8dbcb/
:e6f55cc9-a78e-4727-91f3-0d0623c258ea/
:b358abc2-c1ba-4968-9da9-95e3becf2cda/
:8e8a102d-ac00-47ff-a05c-dc2208b6643e/
:7b44f31c-f78e-4308-87e6-87a77279c2b6/
:893a4288-62ab-4431-bca6-68b5928aa7d9/
:2433ec9b-ab41-4f90-9268-36fd5b3c8c9c/
:34e6a4c0-72ee-4f11-820a-f3b8fdeb6b05/
:03707c06-6c4e-46db-acf0-d97ff2d791fe/
:a6716d99-075e-4001-8030-919ee772b3c6/
:009bf635-944a-4de6-8b6f-52ccc190b2e9/
:d11a727f-bd8e-4b35-91c3-beaadf4fd445/
:ce9edba1-cf35-4d4a-9a2f-6423af523c1a/
```

I would like to set each new terminal window to any (random or round-robin) profile. This, I assume, I could do with a command in `~/.bashrc`.
For that, I require one piece of knowledge:

*How can I change the currently active profile from the command line?*

I know I could manually set it with `right click > Profiles > myprofile`.
I also know I can start a new terminal window with the desired profile using

```bsh
$ gnome-terminal --profile='7e95bbb3-a584-469d-8ae1-75a08287f55a'
```

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114772/606260) since it sounds like no better answers exist

Answer (score 0):

**This answer works but introduces bugs. But [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1274050/606260) is a better solution**

---

```bsh
# install
sudo apt install xdotool
# activate third profile
xdotool key --clearmodifiers Shift+F10 r 3
```

This simulates the keypresses of opening the profile selection menu and choosing an entry. The options to choose numerate from 1 to 9 and then from A to Z.

I'm not entirely happy with this solution because it seems like there should be a way to do this that is more builtin (less hacky) to the gnome terminal.

Source is this [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114772/606260) I just found.

Here's the explanation for why we use `--clearmodifiers`:

> Any command taking the --clearmodifiers flag will attempt to clear any active input
> modifiers during the command and restore them afterwards.
>
> For example, if you were to run this command:
>  `xdotool key a`
>
> The result would be 'a' or 'A' depending on whether or not you were holding the shift key
> on your keyboard. Often it is undesirable to have any modifiers active, so you can tell
> xdotool to clear any active modifiers.
> [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html#clearmodifiers)

---

This means for a random color each time the terminal is opened, you can add to `~/.bashrc`

```bsh
# random color profile
profiles=('0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'u' 'v')
random=$$$(date +%s)
xdotool key --clearmodifiers Shift+F10 r ${profiles[$random % ${#profiles[@]}]}
```

This causes slight lag before the color change though, which is noticeable. It also causes the complete OS to become unusable at times - not even alt tab working anymore. I think that is related to this [open issue](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/43)